# How to put different string resource for different activities with same layout ?

Tags: android, string, imageview

In my android project i want to use a layout i have created multiple times. The problem is that it has 1 Image View and 2 Text View and i want to make 15 different pages(activities) but using the same layout but i don`t know how to change the string source and the image view source. Is it possible to make it like so or i have to create different layout for all the activities?

```
android:text="@string/dlect1"
```

how to change it to

```
android:text="@string/dlect2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string array in resources and drawable array and each activity give it a number and it gets that index from the array

```
<string-array name="texts">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
        <item>6</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="images">
        <item>@drawable/1</item>
        ...
</string-array>
```

And from the code

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.texts)[i];
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.images)[i];
```

Comment: @d.slanchev please check it as answer if it helped you ... to help others and for my reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using Fragments instead of creating 15 activities for this. I don't know for sure what your needs are but you can dynamically set the text in the code (inside a fragment).